# office 365 Access has been blocked by Conditional Access policies. The access policy does not allow token issuance

Tags: azure, yii2, azure-active-directory, office365

I'm trying to send an email with smtp from yii2 application but it fails giving this error in admin portal:
Access has been blocked by Conditional Access policies. The access policy does not allow token issuance.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Its very common for administrators to disable anything but "Modern Authentication" on Azure/Office365. This will prevent using username/password for authenticating with the Office365 SMTP service.

Instead you need to authenticate to the SMTP service using OAuth2
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth